# dll extration from a jar file

Tags: java, jar, relative-path, extract

While extracting the rxtxSerial.dll from the jar file it is giving this exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1383)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1357)
    at weighmentdesk.Weighment.loadJarDll(Weighment.java:940)
    at weighmentdesk.Weighment$5.run(Weighment.java:569)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am locating the file with

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources\\rxtxSerial.dll")
```

is there any problem. If not is there any alternative solution to extract dll file into system root directory (system32).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try like this:
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/rxtxSerial.dll");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quite possibly getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources\rxtxSerial.dll") is returning null
if it's in the root of the jar file try :

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/rxtxSerial.dll")
```

if it's under a dir named resources try :

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/rxtxSerial.dll")
```

and so on...

Comment: u r right it should be forward slash,getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/rxtxSerial.dll")